# How to make vertex a "corner" for subd modifier

Tags: python, interface, vertices, subdivision-surface

I would like to "mark"/"tag" some of the surface vertices as corners for the subdivision modifier. How is this possible? If it is not possible with the GUI is there at least a Python way of accessing and setting this property?

[image]

Edit: there is two ways of manipulating the resulting surface as can be seen in the second screenshot. I would like to use the "Keep Corners" approach. How does Blender determine if it is a corner? There must be some Metadata I guess? Or is a some kind of heuristic.

[image]

Comment: You can try to set the crease factor of neighboring edges to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the so called "vertex crease" weights (see: https://graphics.pixar.com/opensubdiv/docs/using_osd_hbr.html#vertex-creases, I think a better name would be "corner" weights) are currently not implemented but will be in a later version of Blender as discussed here:
https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-3-0-opensubdiv-development/1311217

**Edit:** Beginning with Blender 3.1 this feature is now available:
[image]